# How to send email via php from that database?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello!

Anyone have any idea how to send emails from this query to people who match?

I have a code:
[DBFIDDLE LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cae2e07eac3719ec0aa3b816b601554d)

And I would like to send an email via the button to all people, but with specific parameters. I can send an email one at a time, but in this case I mean sending emails based on matches.
What I mean:

First Email:

```
Email From: MyEmail  
Email to:   tomw@gmail.com  
Body: 
Hello TOM W. 
You are matched with: 
KATE B. Her email: kateb@gmail.com
```

Second Email

```
Email From: MyEmail  
Email to:   markk@gmail.com   
Body: 
Hello MARK K. 
You are matched with: 
KATE B. Her email: kateb@gmail.com
ALEX S. Her email: alexs@gmail.com
```

Third email

```
Email From: MyEmail 
Email to:   kateb@gmail.com  
Body: 
Hello KATE B. 
You are matched with: 
TOM W.  His email: tomw@gmail.com
MARK K. His email: markk@gmail.com
```

Fourth Email

```
Email From: MyEmail 
Email to:   alexs@gmail.com
Body: 
Hello ALEX S. 
You are matched with: 
MARK K. His email: markk@gmail.com
```

Comment: create your email template with placeholders for the params you will pass, i.e instead of `Hello TOM W.` its `Hello {{ NAME }}. `, then get matches from db query, then replace the placeholders with the values from the db when you loop over the matches, plop the template in a db row for a job queue to send etc. Its unclear what your stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

First; create an email template to store on your server. You will use this to insert new content into for each notification.

Call your list of notifications and define the parameters for the email. This can be done one at a time or by looping through an array. In this example, I'm going to just set one set of variables and process the notification.

Format your notification by replacing placeholders with the notification variables.

Now send your notification.

```
// Notification Variables
$to['name'] = 'TOM W';  
$to['email'] = 'tomw@gmail.com';
$subject = 'You got a new match!';
$body = 'Hello TOM W.<br>You are matched with:<br>KATE B. Her email: kateb@gmail.com';

// Process Notification
emailSend($to, $subject, $body);

// This function formats the attributes required to send an email
function emailSend($to_address, $subject, $body){
  
  // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
  $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
  $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
  
  // Additional headers
  $headers[] = 'To: ' . $to_address['name'] . '<' . $to_address['email'] . '>';
  $headers[] = 'From: My Name <MyEmail@example.com>';
  $headers[] = 'Cc: Mike <mike@example.com>';
  $headers[] = 'Reply-To: My Name <MyEmail@example.com>';
  
  // Load notification template and replace placeholder variables in the html file with the notification variables
  $message = emailFormatMessage($subject, $subject, $body);
  
  // Send Notification
  mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}

// This function loads the static HTML file and replaces variables such as {body} with the $body variable we passed to the function.
function emailFormatMessage($title, $preheader, $body){
  $template = file_get_contents(ASSETDIR . '/templates/generic/notification.1.1.html');
  $message = str_replace('%title%', $title, $template);
  $message = str_replace('%preheader%', $preheader, $message);
  $message = str_replace('%body%', $body, $message);
  
  return $message;
}
```